# Java class is displaying encryption password

Tags: java, class, encryption, password-encryption

```
Common\00mpCryptoPassword\00Ljava/lang/String;\00
ConstantValue\00   \00KHETD645%3DJD$%(?!%*)5\00<init>\00()V\00Code
```

I am using `org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor`. I just checked my coded class and found that its byte code displaying my encryption password `KHETD645%3DJD$%(?!%*)5` in class as it is. I really become worried about security of my all data. If someone hack my classes then what'll happen to my data. Why java class is not converting String name `mpCryptoPassword` and value `KHETD645%3DJD$%(?!%*)5` into byte code?

Comment: Why does your code contain a hard coded password in the first place? Why don't you let the users select a password that's stored in a key vault?

Comment: Compilation is not encryption and not even good obfuscation. That's especially true for intermediate formats like bytecode, but even natively compiled code can be reverse engineer given the right skills. If you need your app to have access to the private key, then there's no real way of keeping the private way away from sufficiently resourceful individuals who can get access to your app. It's just one of the fundamental truths about security.

Comment: @Thomas this is not user password(s). This password is used for ecryption and decryption

Comment: Well, a password selected by a user doesn't have to be used to access a system. It can also be used for encryption etc. - It depends on your use case but I assume you're using symmetric encryption, i.e. the one who wants to decrypt the data would need to know the password as well. If it's always the same user then I'd not store that password anywhere and if it was me who'd use your application I wouldn't want to use any password you know as well (i.e. hardcoded).

Comment: Hardcoded encryption keys "hidden" in code (no matter if it is stored as PBE generated byte[] key or as password) are insecure and should not be used if you want to really encrypt something. You should really take one step back and re-thing your application when and how data needs to be encrypted and by what keys. Just encrypting something doesn't make it secure.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a string constant in your code that contains the password for your encryption? If so, string constants are not converted to byte code because there is nothing to convert. It is data. That's why having hard coded string constants for security is easy to crack.

Comment: Even "bytecode" isn't just meaningless bytes for interested parties. Every code that can be executed can be analyzed and reverse engineered. It's just a question of the necessary skills/resources. One can make it *harder*, but not impossible.

Comment: @JoachimSauer --> `One can make it harder, but not impossible` This is what I was looking for as to how can I make harder?

Comment: @taronyu --> `string constants are not converted to byte code because there is nothing to convert` so what is converted into byte code by Java if data is not to be converted?

Comment: Your code is converted to byte code. Byte code are the instructions that are executed by the Java VM. Data is nothing the VM executes.

If you really have to store the password for your class in the code, you can try to obfuscate it by using some sort of encryption on it too. Like a reversible bit shift operation. However, this does not completely eliminate the issue, it makes it just harder. The attacker has to reverse engineer the decoding logic.

Comment: @user230 the name byte _code_ already states it: it's the _code_ (i.e. the instructions) that converted from Java text sources to (intermediate) byte code (which later could be compiled to machine code by the JVM). The data will keep the same in any case.

Comment: @user230: "obfuscation" is the term used to make compiled code harder to analyze/reverse engineer. The saver way to do it is to get rid of the requirement to have an encryption key on-device at all. Usually that's done by moving some of the functionality to a central server (which can run code and contain data that the end-user has no access to).

Comment: @JoachimSauer what about storing passwords in property files as encrypted password `org.jasypt.properties.EncryptableProperties`? I don't have any other server to store them separately

Comment: @user230: what do you think? Do you store the encryption/decryption key on the same device as the encrypted data?

Comment: @JoachimSauer so you recommenced to store it on separate device that is accessible hosted server but not end user. Is there any other way. Can you please reply my question as answer? You really provided very useful hints and tips. I am grateful to you

Comment: If you need the clear-text password (you cannot use a hash) and it is not user-supplied, then you must store the password. Either in clear text (very bad) or somewhat obfuscated (not foolproof either). It's a chicken-and-egg problem. For encrypting a password you need a password. You can use some shifting and shuffling to obfuscate the password but since you have to provide the implementation it can still be reverse engineered. You just keep people from easily extracting the string, but someone who really wants it will still get to it eventually.